# Telerik Kendo MVC UI - ClientFooterTemplate ViewBag value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, client-templates

I am trying to get the value of ViewBag into ClientFooterTemplate as follows:

```
ClientFooterTemplate("<div style='#= (average > 'ViewBag.FBGLG') ? 'color: \\#FF0000;' : '' #'>#:average#</div>");
```

Does not work?

To check the Template I used:

```
ClientFooterTemplate("<div style='#= (average > 7) ? 'color: \\#FF0000;' : '' #'>#:average#</div>");
```

Works great.

I tried:

```
#=ViewBag.FBGLG'# , '@ViewBag.FBGLG', and ViewBag.FBGLG.
```

None worked!!

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Telerik Support, here it is just in case someone else has the same issue:
It should be

```
(average > "+ ViewBag.FBGLG +")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this one "ViewBag.FBGLG" ?

Comment: Can't use double quote inside the clienttemplate.